# How to add text over an image texture in Pyglet

Tags: python, image, video, media, pyglet

I am working with Python 3.8 and pyglet 1.5. I am making a simple video editor, and I need to be able to write text directly over the image texture before it is blitted to the screen, when playing the video. I can't seem to find any info on this anywhere. I have been able to write it to the window, but this creates a flicker and seems to get some text stuck in the buffer. Not sure.

```
txtr = vid.player.get_texture()
txtr.width = vid.twidth
txtr.height = vid.theight
# Would like to add text to txtr here.
txtr.blit(vid.blitpos,0)
```

Comment: maybe it will work with `pillow` and function [Image.Draw.text](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#example-draw-partial-opacity-text)

Comment: Would a normal [pyglet.text.Label](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/programming_guide/text.html) work for you?

Comment: @Torxed I tried Label. It works if you place it directly over the video, but if it is written in any black space, it creates a flickering word.

Comment: @furas I will look into pillow.

Comment: Could you give an example of that code that was flickering? Because I think that's just a miss-use of the combination of video and label *(just a hunch tho)*